# function doesn't return true unless I call it once before I need it

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, control-flow, userdefaults

I have a function called iCloudIsOn() which checks whether a user has opted to use iCloud with the app by comparing the value of a UserDefaults key with a predefined one, and then I am using this on my initial View Controller to sync iCloud and implement pull to refresh, but only if the user is using iCloud, otherwise this code is not needed.

What's strange however is that the function only returns true if I call it right before I need to use it, even with just a print(iCloudIsOn())

The function itself looks like this:

```
func iCloudIsOn() -> Bool {    
    if UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "UDDocumentsPath") == iCloudPath { return true }
    else { return false }
}
```

Then under viewDidLoad of my initial vc:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if iCloudIsOn() {
        // sync iCloud
    }
}
```

This will not work however and iCloudIsOn() will return false at that time unless I add a print(iCloudIsOn()) before if iCloudIsOn() { // sync iCloud }

I tried asking iCloudIsOn to print both the value of the UserDefaults key and iCloudPath every time it is called and they are always identical: file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~cristian~thrive-storage/Documents/

So there isn't something in my code changing the value for one of them at some point (the value is printed before the return).

Any idea on why this is happening? Is it something to do with how UD works or am I missing something else? I find it a little strange, but I'm sure I'm just making a mistake somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't see all your code so I am just philosophizing - do you asynchronously do anything that affects `if UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "UDDocumentsPath") == iCloudPath { return true }` such that it would be `false` moments BEFORE and then as you make the 2nd call, it returns `true`. I.e., the data isn't ready? OR your `iCouldPath` isn't set until the 2nd time around? I know you print `iCloudPath`, but that may not be your problem. Your problem might be the `UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "UDDocumentsPath")` so I'd look into that variable the 1st and 2nd time around

Comment: Hey @impression7vx I tried printing both, so I changed the function to print UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "UDDocumentsPath") and iCloudPath. I wanted to share a screenshot of the console log and I realised that the very first one has an extra '/' but that shouldn't happen because I never change the UserDefaults value manually, I always assign iCloudPath to it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/z423n7leo2fzvid/Screenshot%202019-09-07%20at%2016.56.31.png?dl=0

Comment: Here's how I am assigning the value:

if iCloudIsAvailable() {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(iCloudPath, forKey: "UDDocumentsPath")
}

and iCloudPath is let iCloudPath = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")

Comment: But when do you call that?

Comment: That is called during the app's onboarding only at the moment, so the user is asked whether they want to use iCloud or not, and if they say yes, I change the path where files are stored. So iCloudPath gets stored in UDDocumentsPath and then the app uses the value in UDDocumentsPath everywhere.

Comment: So, can you add the code and the workflow that show all the print statements? In your image you show print statements but it doesn't relate to the current code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199115/discussion-between-cristianmoisei-and-impression7vx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that UserDefaults stored a value without a "/" the first time yet when being compared to the original URL, `iCloudPath`, `iCloudPath` had the original "/".

> UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "UDDocumentsPath") = someURL
>
> iCloudPath = someURL/

This would only happen on the first go around. Workaround is to cover both bases as you don't know which one you are on, especially if you are doing multiple checks in one session of the application.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "UDDocumentsPath") == iCloudPath || UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "UDDocumentsPath").appendPathComponent("/") == iCloudPath
```

Technically, though, this is odd and unexpected behavior.